# UIPageViewController diagonal gestures

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

Didn't find anyone complaining about this, but I couldn't find how to disable diagonal gestures. For instance if you have a pageViewController configured with transition style scroll - horizontal, when you make a vertical swipe and your finger tends towards right or left, it just to another page.

Do you know any way to avoid this?

Best Regards,
fnxpt

Comment: Why do you need to avoid this?

Comment: When you try to make a vertical swipe, mainly on bigger devices like iPhone 6 plus, your finger moves a little bit to the side and changes to another page. I want to lock this or change the sensibility of it

Comment: I see. I've experienced this as well, but I regard it as a glitch in iOS not preventing gestures to be forwarded once they're recognised.

Comment: I notice this on springboard as well, but if you go to weather app, this doesn't happen

Comment: On Whatsapp for instance, if you partially swipe down to open the Notification Center while on a chat with someone, it presses the person's name button on the navigation bar and activates the "more info" view controller.

Comment: Did you found any solution for it?

Comment: I have not. I'd file a bug report: https://bugreport.apple.com/